# Discord bot simple editing its own message gives me error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
module.exports = {
 name: 'hack',

 execute: function(message, args) {
  const user = message.mentions.users.first() || args[0];

  const member = message.guild.member(user);

  if (member) {
   message.channel
    .send('Scrambling Through Database')

    .then((message) => {
     setTimeout(function() {
      message.edit(`Working on hack`);
     }, 4000);
    });

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`Inserting Trojan File on :computer_mouse:`);
   }, 2700);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(member + ` Leaking there passwords to the russians`);
   }, 1700);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`Deleting saved passwords`);
   }, 1700);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`Deleted Epic Account`);
   }, 1700);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`Sent a screenshot of there browser history to there friends`);
   }, 1700);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`Leaking IP Address`);
   }, 1700);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`Leaking users gmail account`);
   }, 1700);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`Completing hack`);
   }, 3700);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`Deleting traces`);
   }, 2000);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`Deleting traces...`);
   }, 2000);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`Copied User Details`);
   }, 2000);

   setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(`A successful hack was complete and it was real`);
   }, 3000);
  } else {
   message.channel.send(
    'Who are you even trying to hack? Is it that tough to mention a user?'
   );
  }
 },
};
```

so this is a simple `!hack @user` command and after you use the command the bot just sends a message and keeps editing its message multiple times but I am getting an error for some reason.
Here's the error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user

Comment: Read the error. `Cannot edit a message authored by another user `

Answer (score 0):

The "message" variable has the exact same name ad the "message" variable in the `client.on('message')` so change it to 'msg' and everything should work fine :

```js
module.exports = {
 name: 'hack',
 execute: function(message, args) {
  const user = message.mentions.users.first() || args[0];

  const member = message.guild.member(user);

  if (member) {
   message.channel
    .send('Scrambling Through Database')

    .then((msg) => {
     setTimeout(function() {
      msg.edit(`Working on hack`);
     }, 4000);
    });

   // all codings

   setTimeout(function() {
    msg.edit(`A successful hack was complete and it was real`);
   }, 3000);
  } else {
   message.channel.send(
    'Who are you even trying to hack? Is it that tough to mention a user?'
   );
  }
 },
};
```

Comment: now i am getting this new error


{msg.edit((member) + ` Leaking there passwords to the russians`)}, 1700)
                         ^

ReferenceError: msg is not defined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Meme Hub Exclusive\commands\hack.js:17:26)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (interna

Comment: Close the `.then()` callback at the end, not just after the first `setTimeout()`